# ActiveCollab API - Get attachment from 'code'

Tags: php, api, activecollab

Which API method we can use to get attachment detailed information by attachment code (for example by this: "FVz6RyPOo4mwh4NUVxoPLjg0tcHuBQt8AS2ggGVv")?

This "code" is returned from /upload-files method - https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/tasks/attachments.html

Comment: Detailed information about this attachment file. For example:
        `"attachments": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "ac.png",
                "mime_type": "image\/png",
                "size": 1927,
                "disposition": "attachment",
                "thumbnail_url": ""
            }
        ],`

Answer (score 0):

There is no API that let you check status of uploaded file by the upload code. Purpose of `/upload-files` API end point, and upload code that you get when you upload a file is to temporaly store files (up to 48 hours) that you later on "claim" by providing that code when adding tasks, comments, file to projects etc. Process is simple:

1. Upload file, and get a code in exchange,
2. Use that code to attach that file to a task, project, comment etc,
3. If code is not used within 48 hours, uploaded file from step #1 is deleted automatically, and code is no longer valid.

This means that uploaded files is not an attachment, until it is claimed and attached to something. Here is an example that explains how you create a task with an attachment:

https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/v1/projects/elements/tasks/attachments.html

Using `/upload-files` for anything other than what I explained above is not a designed process, and therfore there are no extra API-s.